# Python, Tkinter, PIL, Mac problems with displaying images

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I've searched around for a while now here on stackoverflow to find an answer but without any luck! I have problems displaying images using `tkinter` and `PIL` on my mac.     They just cant find the image in the running application. This is the last part of my Python course and I really need to make it work to finish the course. This is the error message I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/andrej/Documents/untitled", line 19, in <module>
imageFile = Image.open("Signori.png")
```

Here is my code:

```
import Image
import ImageTk
import Tkinter

def new():
wind = Tkinter.Toplevel()
wind.geometry('600x600')
imageFile2 = Image.open("nesta.png")
image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageFile2)

panel2 = Tkinter.Label(wind , image=image2)
panel2.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0)
wind.mainloop()

master = Tkinter.Tk()
master.geometry('600x600')
imageFile = Image.open("Signori.png")
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageFile)

panel1 = Tkinter.Label(master , image=image1)
panel1.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0)
B = Tkinter.Button(master, text = 'New image', command = new).pack()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You didn't post the whole exception trace - what was the actual error that was thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
    from PIL, import Images, ImageTk
```

If your image cannot be displayed in a frame, use a label instead:

```
    your_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.open('an image.png')) 
    # note the image has to be in the same directory as your project, 
    # then 
    your_label = Label(master=root, image=your_image) 
    your_label.pack()
```

Answer (score -1):

use this instead
from PIL, import Images, ImageTk
then you image cannot be displayed in a frame, use a label instead

your_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.open('an image.png'))
**# note**
the image has to be in the same directory as your project,
**# then**
your_label = Label(master=root, image=your_image)
your_label.pack()

Comment: try using code blocks with " ` " to make them more readable